# Is the Confidence Interval for a population mean or sample mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, definition

For the calculation of confidence interval, is it the confidence interval for the population mean or sample mean.

This confusion is arising due to the use of standard error in the calculation of the CI and standard error as per what I understand is used for the sampling distribution. This in turn implies that the mean being used for the calculation of CI is the population mean.

If the mean being used was sample mean then the sample standard deviation is the one that needed to be used.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Confidence intervals for the mean are for the population mean. For a normal distribution the sample mean is in the center of the interval.  So it is always in the interval regardless of the confidence level.  The confidence level refers to the percentage of the cases in the long run that such intervals will contain the true population mean.

Comment: The population mean value cannot go into the calculation of the CI, as it is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

The population mean value cannot be used in computing a confidence interval *for itself*. It is unknown, and, if known, what would be the point? You don't need a confidence interval for a known value.

Yes, the standard error (se) is the (estimated) standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the sample mean. That is used in construction of the CI, but does not imply what you think.

From the comments:

Confidence intervals for the mean are for the population mean. For a normal distribution the sample mean is in the center of the interval. So it is always in the interval regardless of the confidence level. The confidence level refers to the percentage of the cases in the long run that such intervals will contain the true population mean. – Michael Chernick

Answer (score 0):

When we are making inference about the population we use the sample point estimate and it’s confidence interval
If we are comparing sample mean to a known population mean, we calculate the confidence interval for the population and then we check whether the sample mean that we calculated lies within the population mean confidence interval of a certain confidence level. Dr. Rana Jaber

Comment: I think you have the second part backwards, because even when testing against a stipulated mean *we still don't know the population mean.*  Thus, you construct a confidence interval based on the sample and check whether the stipulated mean lies within that interval.  "Comparing sample mean to a known population mean" makes little sense: if you know the population mean, you have no need of a sample.